# Netlogo: reporter keeps changing

Tags: return, netlogo

In netlogo v6, I'm trying to let agents interact with other agents in their network, and make new connections.

For that, I need them to check the current links that are also present at the meeting. Only if they are at the meeting, they can interact.

I use a reporter to do this: links_at_meeting.

The code is: (with the patches representing the meeting place)

```
to-report links_at_meeting
  report my-links with [[patch-here] of other-end = one-of (patch-set patch 0 0 ([neighbors] of patch 0 0 ))]
end
```

I keep getting an error that is a bit too unrelated to explain in full, but I figured out that this is due to the fact that links_at_meeting keeps reporting a different number. I found this out because, when I got the error, I went to the command centre and asked for the links_at_meeting of the error-giving turtle, and then I got this (for 1 tick):

```
observer> ask id 39[show links_at_meeting]
(id 39): (agentset, 0 links)
observer> ask id 39[show links_at_meeting]
(id 39): (agentset, 1 link)
observer> ask id 39[show links_at_meeting]
(id 39): (agentset, 1 link)
observer> ask id 39[show links_at_meeting]
(id 39): (agentset, 2 links)
observer> ask id 39[show links_at_meeting]
(id 39): (agentset, 4 links)
observer> ask id 39[show links_at_meeting]
(id 39): (agentset, 0 links)
observer> ask id 39[show links_at_meeting]
(id 39): (agentset, 2 links)
observer> ask id 39[show links_at_meeting]
(id 39): (agentset, 3 links)
observer> ask id 39[show links_at_meeting]
(id 39): (agentset, 0 links)
observer> ask id 39[show links_at_meeting]
(id 39): (agentset, 0 links)
observer> ask id 39[show links_at_meeting]
(id 39): (agentset, 4 links)
```

Here you see that each time I call for links_at_meeting, I get a different agentset for a singular tick (links do not move out of the meeting place during this).

The same happens for a reporter neighbors_at_meeting, which reports the link-neighbors with patch-here = meeting place.

My question is: why? What couldve gone wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out already -

The problem seems to be that this part:

```
my-links with [[patch-here] of other-end = one-of (patch-set patch 0 0 ([neighbors] of patch 0 0 ))]
```

produces a list of links that is on one of those patches, instead of producing a list of turtles that is on any of those patches.

Comment: NetLogo doesn't have a concept of a link being "on" a patch, so I'm not sure what you mean by this.